# How to change navigation bar tint color after setting in Appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift4

I already done the following to change the Navigation Bar Tint color globally:

1) Set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in `info.plist`

2) In Appdelegate I change the color to black :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
}
```

This working fine.All the view controller Navigation bar turn to black.What I want is one of my view controller(only one) the Navigation bar color need to be white.

So my question is,is it possible to change Navigation Bar color for only one View Controller after setting it in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. change the Navigation Bar color even after you set it globally.

You can check for `UINavigationBar` in a view controller and set the tint color.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

It will set the bar button items color to white.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

It will set the navigation bar color to red.

So the global color set in `AppDelegate` will be overridden by the local color for navigation bar in a view controller